# I have doubts about descending gradient and backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

i am a beginner in this from ai and i am learning about gradient descent and its update rule

Is it true that the same gradient is applied to each weight of the network at each step? that is, for example, the gradient is 0.5 because w1 has an error of 0.5

```
then for weight 1 is
w1 = w1-0.5
and for weight 2 it is
w2 = w2-0.5
```

If each weight is updated by applying the same gradient to all the weights of the network, how does it avoid entering a loop? that is to say
w1 has an error of 0.5 and w2 has an error of 0
then now the weights are updated

```
w1 = w1-0.5
w2 = w2-0.5
```

now w1 has an error of 0 and w2 has an error of -0.5
then now the weights are updated

```
w1 = w1 - (- 0.5)
w2 = w2 - (- 0.5)
```

now w1 has an error of 0.5 and w2 has an error of 0
and so it enters a loop, how can this be avoided?

or each weight has a different gradient?
ex:

```
w1 = w1 -  0.5
w2 = w2 -  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post contains a misconception -- the gradient *vector* has an entry for each weight. These entries will usually be different, but it's not *impossible* for 2 weights to have the same gradient.

Your concern about "entering a loop" is a valid one. It most often arises when the weight are all initialized to the same value (e.g. all weights start at 0). The fix is easy enough: initialize weights randomly.